# Automatically generate tags based on Post Object (ACF) titles in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm creating a custom post type for our projects page. I've also made a custom posts type for our employees.

With ACF I've made a Relationship field which where you can add the team members to a project and it's displayed on the website.

Based in the selected team members posts in the relationship field I would like the generate a tag for each title (Employee name) that is loaded in the relationship field.

This is were I'm stuck now.

The name in the Post Object is called teamleden. I've tried adding code to my customs posts type file but it doesn't work.

```html
<?php

// save post action
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_employee_tags_on_save_update', 20);

/**
 * @param $post_id int|string
 */
function set_employee_tags_on_save_update($post_id) {

    // get our current post object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // if post is object
    if(is_object($post)) {

        // check we are on the projects custom type and post statuses are either publish or draft
        // change 'projects' post type to your post type name which has the relationship field
        if($post->post_type === 'projects' && ($post->post_status === 'publish' || $post->post_status === 'draft')) {

            // get relationship field employees
            // this example uses Post Object as the Return Format and is a multiple value
            // change get field param 'employees' to your relationship field name
            $employees = get_field('employees');

            // team member tags to set empty array
            $team_member_tags_to_set = [];

            // if employees has value or values
            if($employees) {

                // get all of our current team member tags
                // change 'team_members' taxonomy value to your members taxonomy name
                $team_member_tags = get_terms([
                    'taxonomy' => 'team_members',
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                ]);

                // empty array for existing team member tags
                $existing_team_member_tags = [];

                // if we have existing team member tags
                if(!empty($team_member_tags)) {

                    // foreach team member tags as team member tag
                    foreach($team_member_tags as $team_member_tag) {

                        // add existing team member to our existing team member tags array by tag ID => tag name
                        // this is so we can use this later to check if a team member tag already exists so we dont create duplicates
                        $existing_team_member_tags[$team_member_tag->ID] = $team_member_tag->name;

                    }

                }

                // foreach employees as employee
                foreach($employees as $employee) {

                    // get the title for current employee
                    $title = get_the_title($employee->ID);

                    // search existing team members array and return the tag id via key
                    $existing_team_member_tag_id = array_search($title, $existing_team_member_tags);

                    // if we have an existing team member tag id
                    if($existing_team_member_tag_id) {

                        // add the existing team member tag id as integer to array
                        $team_member_tags_to_set[] = (int)$existing_team_member_tag_id;

                    } else {

                        // else create a new tag for team member by adding title (name) as string to array
                        $team_member_tags_to_set[] = (string)$title;

                    }

                }

            }

            // remove the action
            remove_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post');

            // set post tags for this post id, removing any unused team member tags if relationship field team members are changed
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $team_member_tags_to_set, $taxonomy = 'team_members', false);

            // re add the action
            add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post');

        }

    }

    // finally return
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested but should get you on the right track.

You will need to add this in your `function.php`.

Reference to things you will need to change in my example code...

1. `projects` post_type is the post type name which this code fires when post is saved or updated.
2. `employees` is the name of the acf relationship field in the `projects` post type.
3. `team_members` is the custom tag taxonomy name which you should have working on your `projects` post type.

Basically what this code does, is when a `projects` post is saved, published or updated using the `acf/save_post` action. It gets the acf relationship field member data for this post. If there are members in the field, it then gets all existing team member tags and creates a simple array of existing member tags by ID => Title(name).

It then loops through all members in the relationship field, and checks if tag already exists for member, if it does it adds the existing member tag `(int)` ID to the `$team_member_tags_to_set` array. If no existing member tag is found, we just add the member title (name) as a `(string)` to the `$team_member_tags_to_set` array.

After all this is done, we simply use `wp_set_post_tags()` passing our `$team_member_tags_to_set` array to update `team_members` taxonomy terms for the current `projects` post.

I've also set append to false in `wp_set_post_tags()` which removes all previous tags and creates a new set of tags. This will help if members get updated in the acf relationship field.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_tags/

See code below, and read my comments so you know whats happening.

```php
<?php

// save post action
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_employee_tags_on_save_update', 20);

/**
 * @param $post_id int|string
 */
function set_employee_tags_on_save_update($post_id) {

    // get our current post object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // if post is object
    if(is_object($post)) {

        // check we are on the projects custom type and post statuses are either publish or draft
        // change 'projects' post type to your post type name which has the relationship field
        if($post->post_type === 'projects' && ($post->post_status === 'publish' || $post->post_status === 'draft')) {

            // get relationship field employees
            // this example uses Post Object as the Return Format and is a multiple value
            // change get field param 'employees' to your relationship field name
            $employees = get_field('employees');

            // team member tags to set empty array
            $team_member_tags_to_set = [];

            // if employees has value or values
            if($employees) {

                // get all of our current team member tags
                // change 'team_members' taxonomy value to your members taxonomy name
                $team_member_tags = get_terms([
                    'taxonomy' => 'team_members',
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                ]);

                // empty array for existing team member tags
                $existing_team_member_tags = [];

                // if we have existing team member tags
                if(!empty($team_member_tags)) {

                    // foreach team member tags as team member tag
                    foreach($team_member_tags as $team_member_tag) {

                        // add existing team member to our existing team member tags array by tag ID => tag name
                        // this is so we can use this later to check if a team member tag already exists so we dont create duplicates
                        $existing_team_member_tags[$team_member_tag->ID] = $team_member_tag->name;

                    }

                }

                // foreach employees as employee
                foreach($employees as $employee) {

                    // get the title for current employee
                    $title = get_the_title($employee->ID);

                    // search existing team members array and return the tag id via key
                    $existing_team_member_tag_id = array_search($title, $existing_team_member_tags);

                    // if we have an existing team member tag id
                    if($existing_team_member_tag_id) {

                        // add the existing team member tag id as integer to array
                        $team_member_tags_to_set[] = (int)$existing_team_member_tag_id;

                    } else {

                        // else create a new tag for team member by adding title (name) as string to array
                        $team_member_tags_to_set[] = (string)$title;

                    }

                }

            }

            // remove the action
            remove_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post');

            // set post tags for this post id, removing any unused team member tags if relationship field team members are changed
            wp_set_post_tags($post_id, $team_member_tags_to_set, false);

            // re add the action
            add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post');

        }

    }

    // finally return
    return;

}
```

Comment: Thx alot for this, I got it it working, the only thing is - is that it now registers to the global tags and not to the custom taxonomy. But I'm already happy with this.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the only thing that it didn't do was register it to the custom-taxonomy but it did register to the general taxonomy tags. Which is fine for me 2 :-)

Comment: Might be worth registering a custom taxonomy for team members, because these member tags will get mixed in amongst your post tags which would be messy. Probably better to keep all member tags consolidated so the search array doesn’t get to big

Comment: So this is where I'm hitting a snag. I've registered the custom taxonomy under team_members, this is the same is the above code. But it's still registering everyting in the general taxonomy Tags. I've been fiddling around with diffrent names etc but it's not changing. It keeps it registered in the general Tags taxonomy. And not the custom one.

Comment: Ahhh i just had a thought, `wp_set_post_tags($post_id, $team_member_tags_to_set, false);` my bad this will just set tags. Let me see if there is alternative

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/ use this instead

Comment: I've been fiddling with this, But when I use it like this wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $team_member_tags_to_set, false); It doesn't do anything.             wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $team_member_tags_to_set,'team_members', false); Also doesn't work.

Comment: So when I use wp_set_post_terms and set $taxonomy = 'post_tag' it is adding the tag to the general tags. But when I change it to team_members, it not working. Also when I use the default category, it's also not saving it there.

Comment: Thats really strange, something might be a wrong with the taxonomy, that should work if your taxonomy is called  `team_members`. Is your taxonomy actually set against the post_type

Comment: I got it working with wp_set_object_terms Thank you for your time and help ;-) wp_set_post_terms only works for the native posts and not the custom posts type

Comment: Ah decent nice one