Setting terms for a custom post type using acf/save_post, the terms come from a 2nd custom post type with an ACF relationship field
I have a two custom post types:

Individual Designs for products (designs) -- this has a set of tags in its own taxonomy for that CPT ('design-library-tags'), and it also has a rating taxonomy for that CPT ('ratings').

I have a Woocommerce store, and the 2nd CPT is a 'product'. I have also created a custom taxonomy for the product's rating. The product's 'product_tag' are the 2nd taxonomy. which hold the product's tags (should be design's tags) and the rating which it should also grab from the design post. Those are called


The process I'd like it to follow is something like this:

Open product
Create relationship to design using the ACF relationship field
Save/update post
When saving, pull the design ID from the ACF field, and then grab the design's tags and rating, so it can be copied into the two custom taxonomies I created for the 'product' CPT (ratings-products & product_tag)

I've got some code here, and I'm dropping cookies to myself so I can kind of see what's happening as things proceed through the function. My issue is that when it gets to the line where it's supposed to grab the terms from the design, I cannot figure out what is going on with it because everything just stops after. There isn't an error, but I also can't read or traverse the object/array of terms. My cookie 'chris_vardump5' never gets created, even though I think I've covered all the scenarios from success to multiple kinds of failures
Here's my code from my functions.php file in my child theme. 'chris_vardump5' never appears in my cookies
//Custom ACF Save to set design themes/ratings when a relationship is established between a product and a design

// save post action
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_design_themes_and_rating_on_save', 20);

/**
 * @param $post_id int|string
 */
function set_design_themes_and_rating_on_save($post_id) {

    // get our current post object
    $post = get_post($post_id);    
    $rating = '';
    $design_themes = array();
    
    //setcookie('chris_vardump1', 'stage 1 - '.serialize($post), time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com');

    // if post is object
    if(is_object($post)) {
        //setcookie('chris_vardump2', 'stage 2 if post object', time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com');

        // check we are on the projects custom type and post statuses are either publish or draft
        // change 'projects' post type to your post type name which has the relationship field
        if($post->post_type === 'product' && ($post->post_status === 'publish' || $post->post_status === 'draft')) {
            //setcookie('chris_vardump3', 'stage 3 post_type=product', time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com');

            // get relationship field employees
            // this example uses Post Object as the Return Format and is a multiple value
            // change get field param 'employees' to your relationship field name
            $designs = get_field('design_name');
            
            if($designs) {
                
                foreach($designs as $design) {
                    
                   setcookie('chris_vardump4', $design->ID, time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com'); 
                   
                   $rating = wp_get_object_terms($design->ID, 'ratings');
                   
                   if( empty($rating) )
                       setcookie('chris_vardump5', 'rating empty', time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com'); 
                    else if ( is_wp_error($rating) )
                       setcookie('chris_vardump5', $rating->get_error_message(), time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com'); 
                    else if( !empty($rating) && !is_wp_error($rating) )
                       setcookie('chris_vardump5', $rating->count, time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com');
                    else
                       setcookie('chris_vardump5', 'total failure', time()+3600*24, '/', 'staging.burlybottomdesigns.com');
                }
                
                
                
            }

            // remove the action
            remove_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post');

        //Set the rating and product tags from the design once we manage to 
        //retrieve them
            //wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $new_rating, 'ratings-products', false);
            //wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $new_design_themes, 'product_tag', false);
            

            // re add the action
            add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post');

        }

    }

    // finally return
    return;

}

EDIT:
This function is called from the WP post edit page when a product is saved, and you cannot output to the JS console or the browser since it refreshes the page and will output nothing if you use commands like echo or print_r or var_dump. That's how I ended up with cookies to check variable values. I manually delete them using Cookie Editor extension in Chrome before each run through. It's not ideal, but it's what the situation allows unless I can learn a new trick.

My original code came from this post on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031825/automatically-generate-tags-based-on-post-object-acf-titles-in-wordpress

Debugging by setting cookies usually isn't a great practice. You could use print_r and echo.
Try using print_r to echo the arrays $rating and $design, and check if some empty.

Sorry, let me provide some context. This function is called from the WP post edit page when a product is saved, and you cannot output to the JS console or the browser since it refreshes the page and will output nothing if you use commands like echo or print_r or var_dump. That's how I ended up with cookies to check.
The issue is still that the result is not popping up as empty, not popping up as WP_ERROR object type. There's got to be more info here.

Thanks for providing context. Does WP_DEBUG_LOG show anything special?
